# Powershell input validition

Tags: validation, powershell, input

I am trying to only allow a user to enter 2 letters when they rename a file if its exists.

It is not working as I wanted it. I am allowed to enter numbers.

if ($RenameLargeFiles.Length -gt '2') {
     Write-Host " You may only enter 2 letters."
     Pause
     Clear-Host
     Rename-LargeFiles

```
 } else {
 Rename-Item -Path $LargeFiles $RenameLargeFiles".txt"
 $LargeFiles = $RenameLargeFiles
 Set-Content -Value $Files -Path $LargeFiles
 }

     }

Set-StrictMode –Version Latest

 $LargeFiles = "C:\PSScripts\LargeFiles.txt"


 $PSScripts = "C:\PSScripts"

 $TestPSScripts = Test-Path "C:\PSScripts"


 switch ($TestPSScripts) {
 'False' { New-Item -Type directory -Path $PSScripts } 
 }






 function Test-Files {
 $Files8 = ""
$Files8 = Read-Host " Please Enter the Complete Path. "

$TFiles8 = Test-Path $files8

if ($TFiles8 -eq 'True') { 
Write-Host $Files8 "LOCATED."
} else {
Write-Host $Files8 "NOT FOUND"
Pause
Clear-Host 
Test-Files
}



}


function Test-LargeFiles {

$LargeFiles = "C:\PSScripts\LargeFiles.txt"

$TestLargeFiles = Test-Path $LargeFiles


if ($TestLargeFiles -eq 'True') {
Write-Host $LargeFiles "already present"
Rename-LargeFiles
} else {
Write-Host $LargeFiles "NOT FOUND."
Write-Host $LargeFiles "created"
}

     }


     function Rename-LargeFiles {
     $LargeFiles = "C:\PSScripts\LargeFiles.txt"

     [string] $RenameLargeFiles = Read-Host " Please Enter 2 letters to rename" $LargeFiles 




     if ($RenameLargeFiles.Length -gt '2') {
     Write-Host " You may only enter 2 letters."
     Pause
     Clear-Host
     Rename-LargeFiles

     } else {
     Rename-Item -Path $LargeFiles $RenameLargeFiles".txt"
     $LargeFiles = $RenameLargeFiles
     Set-Content -Value $Files -Path $LargeFiles
     }

         }




Test-Files

$Files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse $Files8 | Sort-Object -Descending -Property Length | Select-Object -First 10


Test-LargeFiles

Add-Content -Value $Files -Path $LargeFiles



pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regex like so:

```
if ($RenameLargeFiles -notmatch '[aA-zZ]{2}') {
    ... display error message
}
```